# Determining a file's path name from different working directories in python

Tags: python, file, relative-path

I have a python module that is shared among several of my projects (the projects each have a different working directory).  One of the functions in this shared module, executes a script using os.spawn.  The problem is, I'm not sure what pathname to give to os.spawn since I don't know what the current working directory will be when the function is called.  How can I reference the file in a way that any caller can find it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just learned about the `__file__` variable, which will provide a solution to my problem. I can use **file** to get a pathname which will be constant among all projects, and use that to reference the script I need to call, since the script will always be in the same location relative to `__file__`. However, I'm open to other/better methods if anyone has them.

Comment: You can change __file__ to `__file__` by putting backticks (`) around the string. There is also a button (it looks like "101\n010") in the editor to do the same thing.

Comment: It's generally best to use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to get the full path of the module, so that any later changes in CWD don't break it.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a well known directory (/usr/lib/yourproject/ or ~/lib or something similar), or have it in a well known relative path based on the location of your source files that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code will find the location of the *calling* module, which makes sense from a programmer's point of view:

```
    ## some magic to allow paths relative to calling module
    if path.startswith('/'):
        self.path = path
    else:
        frame = sys._getframe(1)
        base = os.path.dirname(frame.f_globals['__file__'])
        self.path = os.path.join(base, path)
```

I.e. if your project lives in /home/foo/project, and you want to reference a script 'myscript' in scripts/, you can simply pass 'scripts/myscript'. The snippet will figure out the caller is in /home/foo/project and the entire path should be /home/foo/projects/scripts/myscript.

Alternatively, you can always require the programmer to specify a full path, and check using os.path.exists if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the materials in this PyCon 2010 presentation on [cross platform application development and distribution](http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/38/) useful.  One of the problems they solve is finding data files consistently across platforms and for installed vs development checkouts of the code.